# Country dependent State/Province list in a custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-enterprise, custom, country-regions

I am new to **magento** and stuck on this problem, I am working on module in which I required a `state` drop down dependent on `country`, like `one page checkout` page. I have the `country` drop down. Can any one help me to show `country` dependent `state` drop down in my custom module.

Answer (score 2):

- First,**your block class should extend** Block class
  `Mage_Directory_Block_Data`. bcoz of this class **generate** country
  dropdown for using function `getCountryHtmlSelect()`

Then add **region and country dropdown using below code at your phtml file**

```
  <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue', "");
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                        </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

- Now,you *need add some javascript code* which will ***change region
  dropdown*** using  below code:

`new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'zip');`

Comment: Sometime region is not loading...